# SF artwork identification - painting of woman looking through a playing card

Tags: story-identification, art

I remember this painting, I think from the eighties, of a woman looking out through a cut out giant playing card. The card was a queen, of course, and her face lined up with the cut out portion of the queen's face.

The background was, as I recall, mostly blues and blacks. Similar in style, possibly even by the same artist, as this cover of "Pawn to Infinity":

[image]

If the book cited a cover artist, I might be able to track it that way. I probably saw it in a magazine such as Omni, or maybe a pulp cover but it could have been from a book.

Comment: Unfortunately [the ISFDB page](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?25765) for *Pawn to Infinity* says "The artist is not credited, no visible signature on the cover."

Comment: Was the woman bald? Was the suit spades, diamonds, hearts, or clubs?

Comment: I had the feeling that one of Zelazny’s Amber books had a cover like that, but I can’t see anything resembling it.

Comment: I don't believe that the woman was bald, probably dark-haired in keeping with the dark blues and blacks of the background.  I'm also thinking that enough of the card may have been cut away to suggest that she was nude behind it, but I couldn't swear to that.

Comment: Possibly a WILDCARDS cover?

Comment: That is an excellent guess, Simon Bucher-Jones, but I was into that series and would have known if that was it.

Comment: http://www.scifi-art.info/scifi-artists.html

Comment: Also, many of the alternate covers for the Avalon series by Bradley match mood and some of the tones.

Comment: I don't recall that image, but the style you are talking about is pretty common for Michael Whelan

Comment: Can't find the one I was looking for, but that style is awfully close to what I remember from an image I saw 20+ years ago.

Comment: This cover from 8-79 is VERY close to the effect of the picture.  https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/29424557-omni-magazine-august-1979